# How to draw 3D model in PyGlet

Tags: python, pyglet, 3d-model

I was able to get a 3D model in .obj format, but I don't know how to draw it on the screen. Here's my code:

```
import pyglet

model = pyglet.resource.model('untitled.obj')
window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    model.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

But it outputs this error:

```
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'\xed\xe5\xe4\xee\xef\xf3\xf1\xf2\xe8\xec\xee\xe5 \xe7\xed\xe0\xf7\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5'
```

If you do the following

```
model = pyglet.resource.model('untitled.obj')
print(model)
```

Output:

```
<pyglet.model.Model object at 0x02E356E8>
```

Comment: Firstly, I would attach a [batch](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/#batches-and-groups) to the resource model, `pyglet.resource.model('untitled.obj', batch=b)` and then do `b.draw()`. Not sure it will solve your immediate issue tho.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple example in the pyglet documentation on GitHub just like this:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=720, height=480)
window.projection = pyglet.window.Projection3D()
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()


@window.event
def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    glRotatef(1, dx, dy, 0)


def rotate(dt):
    glRotatef(0.5, dt, dt, dt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

    model = pyglet.model.load("logo3d.obj", batch=batch)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(rotate, 1/60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure pyglet is just made for 2d stuff. The `.draw()` function rasterisers 2d images pixel by pixel, but more complicated rendering methods are needed for 3d models, even a simple cube. You may need to write a lot more code for this project. A simple way may be to raycast, as in the original doom game, which gives very simple 3d graphics which can have textures. Unfortunately, this method makes complicated shapes impossible and you have to code all the models in your project, not using external sources such as blender. There are numerous methods of compressing a 3d model into a 2d image, but a `.draw()` function just isn't enough. depending on what kind of game/program you're making, you may want to se raycasting or other methods, But I'd recommend using some other game engine t create 3d games. Unity is a good example, unreal engine too.